# Extract Month or Day or Year from Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I would like to know how to get a specific date format (date or month or day or year) from a timestamp. I am wanting to use this in a view with Backbone JS

Comment: Backbone is irrelevant here. You are just talking about JavaScript. Please provide an example timestamp and an example of the type of output you need.

Comment: Also please include your attempts to solve this. Currently, it just looks like you are asking people to do your work for you.

Comment: An example of Timestamp (today) : 1397639141184 i would like to extract April or Wednesday

Comment: Have you looked at the JavaScript [`Date()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)? Doesn't seem like you did much research before posting here... [so] is not an *alternative* to Google...

Comment: I am a beginner with Backbone, Javascript too. This is the first question I ask on Stack. Do not be rude. Too bad it does not matter I'll manage, thank you. :-/

Comment: The person who is being rude is you actually. You've just decided to ask people to do your work for you without even trying to solve this yourself. People are here on their free time and wanting to *help* - not to do others work for them

Comment: I agree, you just have to look 2s on google to find something so basic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date(1397639141184);
alert(d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 2):

1.If it's JavaScript Timestamp(i.e., in milliseconds)

```
var date = new Date(13976391000);
var date = date.getDate(); //returns date (1 to 31) you can getUTCDate() for UTC date
var day = date.getMonth(); // returns 1 less than month count since it starts from 0
var year = date.getFullYear(); //returns year 
// You can also use getHours(), getMinutes() and so on
```

2.If it's database timestamp - example 2013-03-14T02:15:00

```
var date = new Date('2013-03-14T02:15:00'); // Works in all browsers
var date = new Date('2013-10-18 08:53:14');// works in Chrome & doesn't work in IE/Mozilla
//note that its a string and you use the same above functions to get Date,month & year
```

Comment: Regarding 2nd sample, MDN states: The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601). Your shown format is neither. Has to be new Date('2013-10-18T08:53:14');

Comment: I'm using firebug >>> new Date('2013-10-18 08:53:14')
Date {Invalid Date}

Comment: new Date() takes the former format too. // I'm using chrome

Comment: The ISO format is a simplification of the ISO 8601 extended format.   The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Comment: Well that simplification does not work in FF29 and IE11, so you should at least mention that.

Comment: Sorry about it.. I've added now.